# Using Row_Number() Over (Order By Column) When Column is in Different DB Returns Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, row-number

I am submitting the following query in Sql Server (2008)

```
WITH query AS (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY [tbl2].[col2] ASC) AS TableRowNumber ,
    [tbl1].[col1] ,
    [tbl2].[col2]
FROM [db1].[dbo].[tbl1] AS [tbl1]
JOIN [db2].[dbo].[tbl2] AS [tbl2]
    ON [tbl1].[id] = [tbl2].[id])

SELECT
    *
FROM query
WHERE TableRowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 15
ORDER BY TableRowNumber ASC
```

When this query is run, it returns the following error message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'col2'.
```

The sql join itself runs fine (when run as a normal query. The issue seems to be with using the `Row_Number() over (Order By COLUMN)` when `COLUMN` is in a different database from the `FROM` table of the query.

If I would change line 3 to read `(Order By [tbl1].[col1] ASC)` then it runs without any issues. The error only happens when the sort column is in a different DB.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I can't seem to repeat this I'm doing the a cross database join and using a column from the database i'm not executing in in the order by clause and I do not get an error

Comment: I see the same thing. Yaakov, what happens when you leave out the `ROW_NUMBER()` portion altogether? (I bet you still get an invalid column on line 4 or 5). Also what on earth is the purpose of the `TOP 100 PERCENT`?

Comment: maybe I did not get the point, but any particular reason you cannot simply switch tbl1 with tb2 in the FROM-JOIN clause?

Comment: I presume `TOP 100 PERCENT` is the age-old trick to allow ordering in a subquery.  Although it's not necessary if there is no actual `ORDER BY` clause on the query (besides just the row number).

Comment: I know you have said the join works but are you sure that [db2].[dbo].[tb2] isn't supposed to be [db2].[dbo].[tbl2]

Comment: @eddo because the order of the tables in the join really won't matter.

Comment: @Gratzy - yes, it was a typo (these aren't the actual table names in my query - put in fake names for the sake of simplifying it a bit). Fixed.

Comment: ops of course - sorry was mislead by the remark on the change in line 3

Comment: @AaronBertrand when I leave out the `ROW_NUMBER() portion altogether then it runs without any errors. `TOP 100 PERCENT` is probably not necessary (queries are generated automatically, and this may be in there to avoid errors when a view is generated with an `Order By` statement).

Comment: The absolute only way I can reproduce this is if my column name in the Order By clause does not exist in the table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me no problem:

```
SELECT a.name, b.object_id, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.object_id DESC)
  FROM sys.columns AS a 
  INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.objects AS b
  ON a.object_id = b.object_id;
```

So I suspect there is some other issue going on (e.g. `col2` really doesn't exist). Also I noticed that you are calling the thing `tb2` and `tbl2` - is it possible you have both a `tb2` and a `tbl2` in the other database, and you're referencing the wrong one?

**EDIT** I created this:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
GO
USE db1;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl1(ID INT, col1 INT);
GO
INSERT dbo.tbl1 SELECT 1, 5
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 10;
GO
CREATE DATABASE db2;
GO
USE db2;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl2(ID INT, col2 INT);
GO
INSERT dbo.tbl2 SELECT 1, 9
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4;
GO
USE db1;
GO
```

Then ran your query in the context of `db1`. It ran fine. So for the last time I will suggest that there is something you're not telling us about the schema, or perhaps the fact that you've obfuscated the names (and already had to correct one typo from doing so) has obfuscated something too much even for you...

Comment: no. I just wrote in fake table names. just a typo (I'll fix it). And col2 does exist. If I just run the select query leaving out the row_number() part, or even if I just sort on the column from db1.tbl1, it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps the behavior is different with `tempdb` and `sys` versus two "real" dbs

Comment: @YaakovEllis why would you think that (or assume the example I posted was the only one I tried)? It's syntax - the SQL Server parser doesn't give a crap which database you're referencing. I do get the exact same error message as you if I change `ORDER BY b.object_id DESC` to `ORDER BY b.floob`... so once again I suggest you double check your objects, and tell us what happens when you drop the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation from your query altogether, please.

Comment: After dropping the `Row_Number()` calculation it runs without any issues. Please excuse me if my comment offended you. I have had situations in the past where things that I thought would obviously not make a difference ended up making a difference. Was merely exploring a possibility that was reasonable to assume, based on the example that you posted.

Comment: I posted that example because it's something you can test yourself to show that ROW_NUMBER() doesn't have a problem pulling columns or expressions that originated in a different database. I could use two of the databases I have here, but you don't have those databases, do you?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I have posted an updated sample that creates the two tables you've referenced in your query and once again I can execute your query without error. So something else is up. If you don't want to tell us all the details, that's fine, but we're not going to be able to guess at the problem if your obfuscation is masking the real problem.

Comment: "perhaps the fact that you've obfuscated the names has obfuscated something too much even for you"...yup. <hanging-head-in-shame> The actual query had the tbl1 alias in the `Row_Number() Order By` section, which, as you predicted, was the cause of the error </hanging-head-in-shame>. Thanks for the help and well-earned rebukes.